# Xcode error : "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'receiveBatteryLevel' Flutter Platform Channel example on the official Flutter website

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to write native code for my Flutter project using Swift and Xcode and for starters I am following the example on Flutter's official website in the Platform integration section of the documentation at the site below under the swift/ios example,

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-swift-tab

the client-side of the implementation is okay I have followed the code example exactly. However, on the native side in the "AppDelegate.swift" file I am getting the error: "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'receiveBatteryLevel'"

the problem according to Xcode is on this line  "self?.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)"

my code in the AppDelegate.swift is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("myKeyGoesHere(don't mind)")
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
     let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name:"samples.flutter.dev/battery",
       binaryMessenger: controller as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)


    batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
         [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
        // Handle battery messages.
        guard call.method == "getBatteryLevel" else {
           result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
           return
         }
     self?.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)
      })


    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

private func receiveBatteryLevel(result: FlutterResult) {
  let device = UIDevice.current
  device.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
  if device.batteryState == UIDevice.BatteryState.unknown {
    result(FlutterError(code: "UNAVAILABLE",message: "Battery info unavailable",details: nil)
    )
  } else {
    result(Int(device.batteryLevel * 100))
  }
}
```

Comment: either remove the self?. from recieveBatteryLevel(...) or put the function inside your class.

Comment: @john elemans it works, kudos